# Ansible tries to evalue a comand line and fails by builds

Tags: ansible, failed-installation

Trying to insert a  line in the cfg file but seems to try to evaluate it instead and fails as in the example below:

```yaml
- name: Set logging output
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/05_logging.cfg
    state: present
    regexp: '^output:'
    line: '''output:{all: '| tee -a /var/log/test.log'}'''
```

Getting in the logs:

> The error appears to be in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/eda-ami-builder/00_build/ami/eda/packer/ansible/roles/bootstrap/tasks/yum.yml': line 30, column 30, but may
> be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
>     regexp: '^output:'
>     line: '''output:{all: '| tee -a /var/log/cloud-init-output.log'}'''
>                              ^ here
> ```

Comment: Your quotes are unbalanced. What is the exact output you are expecting ? For what it's worth: `'''` is interpreted as an opening single quote followed by an escaped single quote (i.e. two single quotes in a row). I'm afraid your intent was to use a python triple quote which is not how yaml works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark values as [unsafe](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings) in Ansible in order to do this:

```yaml
- name: Set logging output
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/05_logging.cfg
    state: present
    regexp: '^output:'
    line: !unsafe "output:{all: '| tee -a /var/log/test.log'}"
```

Comment: Just tested it and !unsafe really does solve the issue just you need to dismiss the single: ' before output like this:
- name: Set logging output
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/05_logging.cfg
    state: present
    regexp: '^output:'
    line: !unsafe "output:{all: '| tee -a /var/log/test.log'}"

WIth the proposed solution I get in the 05_logging.cfg the following: 

'output:{all: '| tee -a /var/log/test.log'}'   I want instead to be: output:{all: '| tee -a /var/log/test.log'}

Great stuff thanks man!

Comment: Yes the usage of triple quote in your question didn't really made your intent clear here, but now it is.